# How can I run a php script a x number of times?

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have a website that returns a json in this format: domain.tld/json/1/, domain.tld/json/2/, domain.tld/json/3/, domain.tld/json/4/, domain.tld/json/5/ etc.

I know the number of jsons daily, lets say today I have 5. I want to put the number 5 into my field and press get all. The script should loop throught all the pages and insert them into my 2nd website but now it inserts only one page and I don't understand why. Sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
     function request($url) {
    
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://domain.tld");
        
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        
        curl_close($ch);
        
        return $data;
    }

        $count_pages = $_POST["count_pages"];
        
        if(isset($_POST["get_all"])) {
        
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count_pages; $i++) {
            
                $page_number = $i + 1;
                
                $data = request("https://mypage.tld/$page_number/");
                
                $json_data = trim($data);
                
                $json_data = json_decode($data, true);

                $post_title = $json_data["post_title"];
                $post_content = $json_data["post_content"];

        $insert_post = wp_insert_post([
            'post_title'    => $post_title,
            'post_content'  => $post_content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'news',
        ]);


        }
        }
    ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="count_pages" placeholder="Number of pages" style="width:500px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Get all" name="get_all">
        </form>
```

Comment: on this line: " request("https://mypage.tld/$page_number/"); " what $page_number is suppose to do? $page_number is going to be a number, say '1' so the URL will be 'https://mypage.tld/1/' is this what you want? what it is suppose to return to your variable $data?

Comment: With this $data = request("https://mypage.tld/$page_number/");   $data is suppose to become a wp object, which contain page details, but only if the request() function returned some data.

Comment: it should return an array with post_title, post_content. Every single page has a different array with different content. $page_number should be +1 every time the script runs. For example it starts with mydomain.tld/1/. next run should be mydomain.tld/2/ etc untill the cycle of 5 pages is done. All 5 pages have data.

Comment: I have tested your function: function request($url) and it returns the source code of the page with the URL you place, and in your example, your URLs will be in this form 'http://mypage.tld/1/' this URL EVEN if the page exist with this URL will not return an array.its a simple CURL function and you're using a public URL which will return a normal response the same when you visit that page in your browser.

Comment: I'm preparing code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function request($i) {
    
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mypage.tld/json/'.$i.'/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://mypage.tld/");
        
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        return $data;
    }
    
    
  if(isset($_POST["get_all"])) {
      
     for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST["get_all"]; $i++) {
        $json_data = trim(request($i));     
        $json_data = json_decode($data, true);

        $insert_post = wp_insert_post([ 
            'post_title'    => $post['post_title'],
            'post_content'  => $post['post_content'],
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'news',
        ]);
      }

}
```

I can be more of a help if you send me the full response of your page.
Mistake in the code:
https://mypage.tld/$page_number/ should be [https://mypage.tld/json/'.$page_number.'/](https://mypage.tld/json/%27.$page_number.%27/)